# how can i manage name properties of dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, html, post

my jsfiddleis [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RPVE6/)

as you see user can add nw `.sc_name` or new `div` elements via buttons on the page. so when i want to send this form to another page how can i manage `"name"` properties of `inputs`?

i mean i dont know user will add or wont a new input via clicking buttons. so how can i give a new `name` attribute every `input` which is added by  user?

**note:** is there an easy way while using jquery's `sumbit()` function?

Comment: `$(input).attr('name') = 'newName'`?

Comment: Or use array in your names : `<input name="website_name[]" />`. It's easier to get it in your server side.

Comment: @VincentDecaux - depends on the serverside ?

Comment: @Fabricator 'newname' for which one? it would be wrong if i give same name attrs for multiple divs.

Comment: @adeneo True, so let say that PHP can handle it natively. But it's not a W3C spec.